# How do I only render what I see, excluding what I have hidden?

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, camera, visibility

It will be a stupid question but I really don't know how to render the current scene with only the objects displayed in the viewport, as although you normally hide them with H, in the render they are the same.
I thought about creating another scene by deleting those objects, but is it convenient? or does the project weigh me down? moreover, from one scene to another it makes me copy only the single objects and not the collections, is there a way to bring the groups?

So how can I render only some of the objects in the scene without having to go crazy?

Comment: You don't have to go crazy, all you have to do is learn how to use the tools in the outliner. Read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner/interface.html. the camera icon determines what gets rendered, the eye icon determines what is visible on the viewport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You need to select the filter in your scene view window, and make sure that the camera is enabled. This allows you to make certain objects not render in the viewport.

Bonus Tip:
If you have many different objects to turn off final render visibility on, select all objects you don't want to be rendered. Set the active object (yellow highlighted) in the scene viewer to be turned off in renders. Then once the camera icon is turned off for the active object, right click the icon and around the bottom of the pop up window, select copy to selected. This will set all other selected objects to have the same value as whatever you right clicked on. This also works for things like modifier settings, loc/rot/scale values, and much more.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip!