# Why is my donut icing being rendered in two colors with cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, color

When I render this donut with Cycles in Blender 3.0, the icing coloration does something weird and starts to have these two different brown colors in certain areas. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: 2 meshes in one place, maybe? 1.  Check for hidden but rendering objects, 2. H Hide a few faces to see whether you have duplicate geometry.

Comment: HI Robin, thanks for the reply, not sure I know how to check for those two things...could you maybe describe how I might do this? it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 1. for hidden but rendered objects have a look at the "eye" icon and the "camera" icon in the outliner. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208157/107598) and [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50891/107598) for details. -- 2. switch to *Edit* mode & press key 3 for *Face Selection* mode. Then select a face. With key H you can hide it (Alt+H=unhide). Inspect faces with bad shading to see if there are overlapping faces -- 3. Also, check the normals (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598). Red areas are bad. Alt+N, Recalc Outside in Edit mode to fix it

Comment: looks like i have some hidden/overlapping mesh. is there a way to procedurally fix this easily for the whole icing? @Blunder

Comment: You may have 2 overlapping meshes within the object, if they don't have any common vertices, you will easily select one if you put your mouse on the mesh in Edit mode and press L, then move. You can also try to select all and press M > Merge by Distance. Or you can share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/